# Use GROUP_CONCAT() to generate polygons in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat, spatial-query

I have a table that has columns `zone`(name of the zone which is a string), `longitude` (decimal), `latitude` (decimal), `logical order` (integer).

`logical_order` indicates the order in which the coordinates can be combined to create the polygon. For example, each zone will have multiple rows in this table with different `longitude`, `latitude`. For each zone row, the `logical_order` will start at 1 (for starting point) and increase by one per row. For example, if a zone has 3 points, `logical_order` will run from 1 through 3. Coordinates at 3 are not the same as at 1. In other words, the coordinates do not close the polygon.

I'm trying to create `POLYGON` by grouping coordinates of each zone and using spatial package as below:

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT t0.zone, ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT("'POLYGON((", GROUP_CONCAT(t0.coordinate ORDER BY t0.logical_order SEPARATOR ','), "))'")) FROM
(
    (SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, logical_order FROM zones)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 1000 AS logical_order FROM zones WHERE logical_order = 1)
) t0 
GROUP BY t0.zone
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.
```

How can I fix this error? Am I approaching the right way?

EDIT:

If I try without the `ST_GeometryFromText()` in the second query, I get a string like:

```
POLYGON(77.5068350000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -11.4907909800)
```

After adding two parenthesis like below still give the same error:

```
POLYGON((77.5068350000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -11.4907909800))
```

EDIT 2:

I also manually checked one by one for each zone for polygon closure which is fine. I have increased the limit on character number of `group_concat()` too. But the error still persists.

EDIT 3:

SQL fiddle with sample data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5094e5/5

Comment: Can you select out the polygon itself first, just to check it appears valid? But think you need an extra set of brackets around the coordinates.

Comment: @Kickstart I tried with 2 brackets like in the edit but I still get the error.

Comment: You need quotes around the POLYGON(()) function.

Comment: @Kickstart already tried that. There was also a limit on the `group_concat()` number of characters which i increased in session. But still the same error.

Comment: With quotes it worked for me - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4280/1 . You can adjust the GROUP_CONCAT() max length if required.

Comment: @Kickstart :O Am I adding the quote wrongly in my `concat()`?

Comment: Your code looks OK for the concatenation. But when I tried what should be output it does work.

Comment: @Kickstart Very strange. Is it because `group_concat()` result is not available at the execution time of `ST_GeometryFromText()`?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) in db exchange. You can refer to the actual answer and discussion [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206746/use-group-concat-to-generate-polygons-in-mysql/206749#206749).

There was a few issues:

1. Default value for number of characters `group_concat_max_len` was too low cutting off some coordinates
2. Double quotes used in the outermost `CONCAT()` was causing problems. Needed to use single quotes
3. The way I had closed the polygon using `GROUP BY` was questionable.

For the benefit of future users I will copy that answer here:

The error is likely cause because the "cycle" isn't closed, i.e. last point in the polygon does not match the first one.

This can be from two issues:

- the [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) setting is too low (default is 1024).

Solution: increase it, either in the server or session level.

- the error-prone `GROUP BY` used to add the additional point.

The `GROUP BY` you use is prone to give wrong results, as it may not always select the row you want (`WHERE logical_order = 1`) to read the coordinates:

```
(
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           logical_order 
    FROM zones
    UNION
    -- This is to close the polygon by adding the first coordinate also 
    -- as the final coordinate of the zone. 
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           COUNT(zone) + 1 AS logical_order 
    FROM zones 
    GROUP BY zone
) t0
```

I'd write it like this:

```
(
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           logical_order 
    FROM zones
    UNION ALL
    -- This is to close the polygon by adding the first coordinate also
    -- as the final coordinate of the zone. 
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude), 
           1000000     -- unlikely to have a million points polygon
    FROM zones
    WHERE logical_order = 1
) t0
```

Final working query:

```
SELECT t0.zone, ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT('POLYGON((', GROUP_CONCAT(t0.coordinate ORDER BY t0.logical_order SEPARATOR ','), '))')) FROM
(
    (SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, logical_order FROM zones)
    UNION
    (SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 10000 AS logical_order FROM zones WHERE logical_order = 1)
) t0 
GROUP BY t0.zone;
```

Need to set the `group_concat_max_len` appropriately.